# How to pass data from class to page in php?

Tags: php

I want to get member data from class that has been defined in other page.Suppose page 1 contains that class , how do i get that data in page 2.

Code looks something like this:

**page 1**

```
class gamecard {
    function save_order($json_order){       
        if($payment_method=='Paypal') {                
            $vpcURL = $pp->buildCheckoutUrlTest($json_order);                                   
            }   
        return json_encode(array('order' => $order,
                                    'errID' => $errID, 
                                    'errMess' => $errMess
                                    ));         
    }
}
```

**page 2**

```
print_r($vpcURL);
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On page2

```
require 'page1.php';

$obj=new gamecard();
$obj->save_order('Pass your variable');
echo $obj->$vpcUrl;
```

I will ask you to make some modifications in the game card itself.

I would do something like this

```
class gamecard {
    public $vpcURL;
        function save_order($json_order){       
            if($payment_method=='Paypal')              
                $this->vpcURL = $pp->buildCheckoutUrlTest($json_order);                                   
            return json_encode(array('order' => $order, 'errID' => $errID,'errMess' => $errMess));         
        }
    }
```

Comment: i try to it. But in my case: i can do $obj=new gamecard(); just once and can't  $obj=new gamecard(); again!

Comment: @HoangAloevera You don't have to initialize the object again. Just repeat `$obj->save_order('Pass your variable');`line.

Comment: yes sir. I know what your mean. but in page 2 I cant call ('Pass your variable'). Can you help me another solution?

Comment: cant call as in ?

Comment: because from page 1 value of (''Pass your variable'') is null

Comment: can you update your question with what you did and what was the error that came, i will help you out.

Comment: @HoangAloevera pleasure :)

Answer (score 0):

if you can reach the instance of gamecard on page2, you could write a getter/setter function for vpcURL. Set $vpcURL as member variable and get it via getter.

If you can't access the instance from page2, then you could do it over a static method

Answer (score 0):

Well, one way is to include the gamecard class in page 2 and make a global variable of $vpcURL. then call upon that method from page 2.